# Implement pagination without flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pagination, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to remove the dependence of `flask-SQLAlchemy` from my application. Although, I rely pretty heavily on the `pagination` functionality that comes with the library. I would like to move the pagination ability to my models.

Looking inside `flask-SQLAlchemy`, I see the following:

```
class Paginate(object):
    def __init__(self, query, page, per_page, total, items):

    @property
    def pages(self):
        """The total number of pages"""
        if self.per_page == 0:
            pages = 0
        else:
            pages = int(ceil(self.total / float(self.per_page)))
        return pages
    ...

class BaseQuery(orm.Query):
    ...
    def paginate(self, page=None, per_page=None, error_out=True):
        ...
        return Pagination(self, page, per_page, total, items)
```

This functionality is called like below:

```
page = Model.query.filter(*where_to_SQL(Model, where)).paginate(page=1, per_page=chunksize)
```

If I have defined my `SQLAlchemy` declarative model as below, how might I add pagination with a minimal change to my codebase?

in `database.core.py`, from where the `Model` class is imported and used in model definitions...

```
...
Model = declarative_base(name='Model')
Model.query = db_session.query_property()
...
```

Comment: Just copy the relevant code?